# How to `parfor` nested loops?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

The **original code** is like this:

```
for i = 1 : size(H, 1)
    for j = 1 : size(H, 2)
        H{i,j} blabla
```

and I tried to adapt it into **parallel code** like this:

```
parfor ind = 1 : numel(H)
    [i, j] = ind2sub(ind);
    H{i,j} blabla
```

which generates an error saying `parfor` cannot run due to H{i,j}.

**Then what's the error here? And how can I adapt the nested loop into parfor?**

**One possible solution** is

```
for i = 1 : size(H, 1)
    parfor j = 1 : size(H, 2)
        H{i,j} blabla
```

But I doubt using a parfor within another loop will multiply the overhead of `parfor` which results in **additional computation time**.

Comment: I suspect that `H{i,j} blabla` might be modifying your cell array `H` in some way - in that case when you try to run in parallel you don't know what modifications have or haven't already happened.

Comment: What exactly do you have under the cell array `H`, i.e. `H{i,j}`? Like  what kind of data are we dealing with there?

Comment: Did you try `parfor ind = 1 : numel(H), H{ind} blabla, end`? This should be fine.

Comment: Currently I'm working on a workaround like @Daniel's comment. However a certain thread stops at some point which results in a total failure in the program.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error for using parfor is that Matlab is unable to detect that `[i,j]` is unique through the loop because it is the result of a function. Thus, for the engine, you may access to `H{i,j}` multiple times, iterations are not analyzed to be independent from each other.

Edit: as mentioned by patrik, you have to be sure that there is no dependence between two iterations, that is here `H{i,j}` does not depend on `H{k,l}`, `i!=k and j!=l`, nor the value of a variable in the iteration is used in another iteration. This requirement is the basic one to allow a parfor, except from [reduction assignment](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/distcomp/getting-started-with-parfor.html#brdqg4q-1).

Besides that point, if you want to run independent computations in parallel, and if it worth it, always choose to `parfor` the outermost loop. In addition to this, remind that [Matlab does not allow nested `parfor`](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/optim/ug/improving-performance-with-parallel-computing.html); instead, you have to make a function which runs a `parfor` if you want to parallelize inner for-loops. The parallelization of inner loops may not bring a speed-up (depends on how many workers are there in the parpool).

From my experience, it is not recommended to run parallel inner loops. As an example (outside Matlab), I would cite LibSVM, which recommends to parallelize only the outermost loop with openmp if you want to speed-up the computation, never other inner loops.

The reason of this recommendation is that you have a limited pool of workers, and workers may be viewed as threads; there is a limit where if you add threads, the computation run slower because of the time of switching between threads. Matlab may manage this part very well, but the point is that you will have a pool of workers limited in size. If each outermost iteration takes a lot of time and if you have many iteration, you will gain no time to parallelize inner loops because each worker will be busy to run the whole iteration (including inner loops).

Nevertheless, it's always a good thing to test each option, some of them may be counter-intuitively more adapted to your problem!

Comment: It would be good to also mention that there cannot any internal dependencies, such as `H{i,j}` cannot depend on `H{k,l}` `k~=i, l~=l` this can cause program to halt: Eg if thread A needs to finish before thread B can start and thread B needs to finish before thread A can start. This is of course mentioned by you, but in this case I guess this deserves to be mentioned explicitly.

Comment: @patrik This is indeed good to notice, I supposed it was not the case in the OP. I edit my answer right now to add a precision for that, thk

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the linear index to assign into H? For example:

```
H = cell(4, 4);
parfor idx = 1:16
  [i, j] = ind2sub([4, 4], idx);
  H{idx} = rand(i, j); % or whatever
end
```

Otherwise, it's always best to make the outermost loop the PARFOR loop. The following also works:

```
H = cell(4, 4);
parfor r = 1:4
  for c = 1:4
    H{r, c} = rand(r, c);
  end
end
```